# How many different passwords of length $10$ have $3$ A's and $7$ digits such that no two A's are adjacent?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I have this question. Apparently my solution is wrong and I want to know why it's wrong. The question is:

> How many different passwords of length $10$ have $3$ A's and $7$ digits such that no two A's are adjacent?  The digits are from $0-9$.

*My solution:*

_A_A_A_   thus $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 7$, where $x_2 \geq 1$ and $x_3 \geq 1$

Therefore, there are $7-1-1 = 5$ (identical) digits to put in $4$ distinct spots.

Using combination with repetition formula:  $(5+4-1)C5 = 8C5$

Then since there are $10$ digits, with repetition allowed, there are $10^7$ ways.

Answer: $8C5 \cdot 10^7$

But apparently this answer is wrong.  Can someone please provide the correct step-by-step solution for this problem and where I went wrong?

Comment: "*But apparently this answer is wrong*"  What makes you say that?  I follow your logic, would have approached the same way, and don't see any mistakes at the moment.

Comment: answer key is 10C7 * 10^7,  with no explanation

Comment: $\binom{10}{7}\cdot 10^7$ is the answer to the question of how many passwords of length $10$ have exactly three $A$'s and the rest as digits with *no other restrictions.*  That counts passwords where the $A$'s are potentially adjacent and is incorrect as an answer to the question as you have written it where $A$'s may not be adjacent...  Your answer is indeed the correct one.

Comment: hmm okay, thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  As JMoravitz said, your answer is indeed correct.

Comment: Repetition of digits allowed here????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JMoravitz stated in the comments, your answer is correct.  Let's confirm it.

**Method 1:**  We use the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

We choose three of the ten positions for the $A$s, then fill each of the remaining positions with one of the ten digits, which can be done in 
$$\binom{10}{3}10^7$$
ways.  From these, we must subtract those arrangements in which at least one pair of $A$s are adjacent.

*A pair of $A$s are adjacent*:  We have to arrange nine objects: $A$, $AA$, and seven digits.  There are nine ways to choose the position of the $A$ and eight ways to choose the position of the $AA$.  Each of the remaining seven positions can be filled with a digit in $10$ ways.  Hence, there are 
$$9 \cdot 8 \cdot 10^7$$
such arrangements.

However, if we subtract the number of arrangements with a pair of $A$s from the total, we will have subtracted too much since we will have subtracted each arrangement with two pairs of consecutive $A$s twice, once for each way of designating one of the pairs as the pair of consecutive $A$s.  We only want to subtract such arrangements once, so we must add them back.

*Two pairs of adjacent $A$s*: Since we only have three $A$s, this can only occur if we have the block $AAA$.  We have eight objects to arrange: $AAA$ and the seven digits.  There are eight ways to place the block $AAA$.  Each of the remaining seven places can be filled with a digits in $10$ ways.  Hence, there are 
$$8 \cdot 10^7$$
such arrangements.

By the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, the number of admissible arrangements is 
$$\binom{10}{3}10^7 - 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 10^7 + 8 \cdot 10^7 = \left[\binom{10}{3} - 9 \cdot 8 + 8\right]10^7 = (120 - 72 + 8)10^7 = 56 \cdot 10^7 = \binom{8}{5}10^7$$

**Method 2:** We arrange the seven digits, then insert the $A$s in the spaces between them or at the ends of the row.

Since we have $10$ choices for each of the seven digits, we can arrange seven digits in a row in $10^7$ ways.  This creates eight spaces, six between successive digits and two at the ends of the row.
$$\square d_1 \square d_2 \square d_3 \square d_4 \square d_5 \square d_6 \square d_7 \square$$
To separate the $A$s, we must choose three of these eight spaces in which to place an $A$, which can be done in $\binom{8}{3}$ ways.  Hence, there are 
$$\binom{8}{3}10^7 = \binom{8}{8 - 3}10^7 = \binom{8}{5}10^7$$
admissible arrangements.